# mapping all available devices in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a working docker-compose where I now need to bind not only one specific device but all available devices.

So instead of having something like:

```
devices
  - '/dev/serial0:/dev/serial0'
```

I would like to do something like:

```
devices
  - '/dev:/dev'
```

This gives me the following error:

```
container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:70: creating device nodes caused \\\"open /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/6a4...05af/rootfs/dev/pts/0: permission denied\\\"\"": unknown
```

How could I map all devices to my container?

Comment: Do you actually want to run this process in a Docker container?  It sounds like you don't want the isolation that provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this most easily by running a privileged container:
e.g compare:

`docker run alpine ls -la /dev`

vs

`docker run --privileged alpine ls  -la /dev`