# docker-compose devices map all devices from local to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tty

I have this docker-compose service that i am trying to make work.

```yaml
  app:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated
    devices:
      - ${DEVICE:-/dev/null}:-/dev/ttyUSB*
```

Response when running `docker-compose up app`

```
Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/ttyUSB*": no such file or directory
```

The idea here is to get all devices that match `/dev/ttyUSB*` from local and create them inside the container. This way i can have 0-N devices in the container, handling scenarios when no devices are connected. Also I do not have to know each device's `tty<id>`

I have read some old answers like this one :
[mapping all available devices in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455982/mapping-all-available-devices-in-docker-compose)
but these either use

`--privileged` or do not answer the question of how to get (all | no devices) copied and accessible.

I am aware that:

```yaml
app:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated
    devices:
      - ${DEVICE:-/dev/null}:-/dev/ttyUSB0
```

works but not when the device is assigned a different number, hence the need to map them all.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Not yet brother... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose` able to read `YAML` from `STDIN` so just generate it on the fly.

Let's say that our original file is:

```yaml
abc:
  container_name: abc
  image: alpine
  entrypoint: ["watch", "-n", "5", "ls"]
```

And devices are:

```bash
$ ls -l /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 4, 64 Nov 11 09:34 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 4, 65 Nov 11 09:34 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 4, 66 Nov 11 09:34 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 4, 67 Nov 11 09:34 /dev/ttyS3
```

So, let's add these device to `YAML`:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n%s' "$(cat docker-compose.yml)" "$(if [ "$(ls /dev/ttyS*)x" != "x" ]; then echo -e "  devices:"; for D in /dev/ttyS*; do echo "    - ${D}:${D//ttyS/ttyUSB}"; done; fi )"
```

will print:

```yaml
abc:
  container_name: abc
  image: alpine
  entrypoint: ["watch", "-n", "5", "ls"]
  devices:
    - /dev/ttyS0:/dev/ttyUSB0
    - /dev/ttyS1:/dev/ttyUSB1
    - /dev/ttyS2:/dev/ttyUSB2
    - /dev/ttyS3:/dev/ttyUSB3
```

Now let's try to run docker container using `STDIN`:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n%s' "$(cat docker-compose.yml)" "$(if [ "$(ls /dev/ttyS*)x" != "x" ]; then echo -e "  devices:"; for D in /dev/ttyS*; do echo "    - ${D}:${D//ttyS/ttyUSB}"; done; fi )" | docker-compose -f /dev/stdin -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

```
Creating abc ... done
```

Let's attach to container and check devices:

```bash
$ docker exec -it abc sh
# ls -l /dev
...
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,  64 Nov 11 11:06 ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,  65 Nov 11 11:06 ttyUSB1
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,  66 Nov 11 11:06 ttyUSB2
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,  67 Nov 11 11:06 ttyUSB3
...
```

**Profit**

<sub>Also, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498747/13946204)</sub>

Comment: you can do `-f -`. no need for `/dev/stdin`

Comment: @TheFool I found [this old bug](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3440) and avoided to use `-`. But, probably yes, it may be used

Comment: I see how this might work, but this method assumes that the last line/element of the docker-compose file is devices.

Comment: @SlavKirilov you may add `{{DEVICES}}` placeholder at any place of `docker-compose` file and use `sed` instead of `printf` to replace it (`cat docker-compose.yml | sed "s\{{DEVICES}}\${SOME_FORMATED_DEVICES_VARIABLE}\g"`). This method assumes any operation that you able to run with bash

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer in the spirit of last comment, so i can accept it and people will have a solution that be it long as it is can be aliased and used in other tools :)

Comment: 1. my solution already working. 2. my solution completely solving the problem describing in the question and may be used as is. 3. I described way how your problem may be solved and do not plan do your work for you (at least for free). 4. Even if I would like to update answer for your specific case, I can't do it beacuse I don't know real docker-file format and device names

Comment: Ok man i just think that the `sed` way is better in general since it does not rely on what your docker-compose is or to be more specific where devices is.

Comment: @SlavKirilov It is just an example. Actually I don't like `sed` because you have to add `{{DEVICES}}` placeholder inside `YAML` and that can't be used without dynamic modification anymore. However in your specific case that may be a best solution. In other way you may separate `docker-compose.yml` for multiple files and modify dinamically only minimal `docker-compose-with-devices.yml` (where `devices` may be placed at the end) and other information will be included in `docker-compose-other-services.yml` file. In this case you should add `-f docker-compose-other-services.yml` extra parameter

Comment: I'm happy this is here, forgive my ignorance, just trying to get it. Appreciate all the answers you gave.